# How can I use coalescing operator in Haxe?

Tags: operators, haxe, null-coalescing-operator, coalescing

As I mentioned in the question,

How can I use coalescing operator in Haxe?

Comment: Starting with Haxe 4.3.0, the null coalescing operator is supported. https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/releases/tag/4.3.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Haxe does not have a null coalescing operator like C#'s `??`.

That being said, it's possible to achieve something similar with [macros](https://haxe.org/manual/macro.html). It looks like somebody has already written [a library](https://github.com/skial/nco) that does exactly this a few years ago. Here's an example from its readme:

```
var s = Sys.args()[0];
var path = s || '/default/path/to/../';
```

It uses the existing `||` operator because macros can not introduce entirely new syntax.

---

However, personally I would probably prefer a [static extension](https://haxe.org/manual/lf-static-extension.html) like this:

```
class StaticExtensions {
    public static function or<T>(value:T, defaultValue:T):T {
        return value == null ? defaultValue : value;
    }
}
```

```
using StaticExtensions;

class Main {
    static public function main() {
        var foo:String = null;
        trace(foo.or("bar")); // bar
    }
}
```

Instead of making your own, you could also consider using the [`safety` library](https://github.com/RealyUniqueName/Safety#static-extensions-for-null-safety), which has a number of additional static extensions for [`Null<T>`](https://api.haxe.org/Null.html) and features for dealing with `null` in general.

Comment: Thanks for extension contribute. I will use it!

Answer (score 3):

Use this addon:

https://github.com/skial/nco

Then, type

`var value = a || 'backup value';`

instead of

`var value = (a == null) ? 'backup value' : a;`

Answer (score 1):

You can also utilize abstracts instead of macros for this purpose

```
class Test {
  static function main() {
    trace("Haxe is great!");
    var s:Ory<String> = "hi!";
    trace(s || "I don't get picked");
    s = null;
    trace(s || "I get picked");
    trace(s + "!");
  }
}
@:forward abstract Ory<T>(T) from T to T {
  @:op(a||b) public inline function or(b:T):Ory<T> {
    return this != null ? this : b;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hm.. good point, but not sure how practical this is because you have to type it as `Ory<T>` first.

Comment: Since people [seem to] most often want this for optional argument processing and alike, typing those as Ory<> is relatively small price.